# File Input accept every type of file, but not video and image

Tags: html, file, file-upload, filepicker

I want to implement an HTML5 file picker `<input type="file" ...>` which accepts all kinds of files.

**But it should let the user select** `image/*` and `video/*` files.
To be more precise: I'm trying to disallow images and videos. Anything else should be allowed.

The only way I currently see is to define a set of accepted file extensions (and/or mime types), but I don't think it's feasible to add a list of hundreds of mime types just to prevent that the user can select image and video files. So that wouldn't be a satisfying solution.

I'd prefer a JavaScript free solution, if possible.

Comment: Your question isn't clear... are you trying to disallow video and images?  Or only allow video and images?  If allowing, you can set `image/*` and `video/*` on the `accept` attribute.  There is no way to disallow.

Comment: I'm trying to disallow images and videos. Anything else should be allowed.

Comment: This isn't possible without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Below link will help you in resolving your problem basically you need to add `accept` attribute to your input element and add the file types as the value which you want the user to upload. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: Hi. The problem is, that I want the user to be able to upload all kinds of files. But not images and videos. Therefore I'd have to specify a subset of all possible extensions and/or mime types (but without video and image types). That wouldn't be a good solution imho.

Comment: According to my knowledge, There is no direct way to disallow them but you can use javascript to check for file extension using regex pattern when there is a change event in the input and based on that alert the user otherwise allow them.